# i have integrated nodejs backend to reactjs front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, integration, webapi

hi i have integrated nodejs backend to reactjs front end. i have done these ways. but it shows error . i am new to react pls help.

```
function Register() {

 const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    password: "",
    confirmpassword: "",
  });

const InputEvent = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

setData((preVal) => {
      return {
        ...preVal,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };

const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const registered = {
      name: "data.name",
      phone: "data.phone",
      password: "data.password",
    };
    
    const isValid = formValidation();
    if (isValid) {
      //if form is valid, route
      axios
        .post(`https://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register/`, registered)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      history.push("/myvehicles" );
    }
  };

return (
    <div className="signup__container">

      <form className="register__form" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
        <h5 className="h5__form"> Name</h5>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="पुरा नाम लेख्नुहोस्"
          name="name"
          value={data.name}
          onChange={InputEvent}
        />
           
          );
        })}
        <h5 className="h5__form"> phone </h5>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="फोन लेख्नुहोस्"
          name="phone"
          value={data.phone}
          onChange={InputEvent}
        />

       
          );
        })}
        <h5 className="h5__form"> Password </h5>
        <input
          type="Password"
          placeholder="पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्s"
          name="password"
          value={data.password}
          onChange={InputEvent}
        />

       
          );
        })}
        <h5 className="h5__form"> Confirm Password </h5>
        <input
          type="Password"
          placeholder="पुन: पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्"
          name="confirmpassword"
          value={data.confirmpassword}
          onChange={InputEvent}
        />

      
          );
        })}
        <p>
          <button type="submit" className="signup__registerButton">
            Register Now
          </button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

the code is as above when i run both backend and front end server and post values from UI. it gives error. the error comes from the post function. if i am doing wrong pls correct.

Comment: "it gives error" what error?

Comment: You can remove double quote because you pass wrong parameters and http instead of https in your url.
 const registered = {
      name: data.name,
      phone: data.phone,
      password: data.password
    };

Comment: Try http instead of https in your url

Comment: there are 3 errors! They are:

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.

 POST https://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register/  net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR                              xhr.js:177

Comment: if i use http it gives this error:

xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register/ 400 (Bad Request)

Error: Request failed with status code 400                  register.js
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)      
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove **double quotes** because you pass the wrong parameters and http instead of https in your api url.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
        
        export default function App() {
          const [data, setData] = useState({
            name: "",
            phone: "",
            password: "",
            confirmpassword: ""
          });
        
          const InputEvent = (event) => {
            const { name, value } = event.target;
        
            setData((preVal) => {
              return {
                ...preVal,
                [name]: value
              };
            });
          };
        
          const formSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const registered = {
              name: data.name,
              phone: data.phone,
              password: data.password
            };
        
            const isValid = formValidation();
            if (isValid) {
              //if form is valid, route
              axios
                .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register/`, registered)
                .then((res) => {
                  console.log(res);
                  console.log(res.data);
                })
        
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
        
              // history.push("/myvehicles" );
            }
          };
        
          return (
            <div className="signup__container">
              <form className="register__form" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
                <h5 className="h5__form"> Name</h5>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="पुरा नाम लेख्नुहोस्"
                  name="name"
                  value={data.name}
                  onChange={InputEvent}
                />
                <h5 className="h5__form"> phone </h5>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="फोन लेख्नुहोस्"
                  name="phone"
                  value={data.phone}
                  onChange={InputEvent}
                />
                <h5 className="h5__form"> Password </h5>
                <input
                  type="Password"
                  placeholder="पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्s"
                  name="password"
                  value={data.password}
                  onChange={InputEvent}
                />
                <h5 className="h5__form"> Confirm Password </h5>
                <input
                  type="Password"
                  placeholder="पुन: पासवर्ड लेख्नुहोस्"
                  name="confirmpassword"
                  value={data.confirmpassword}
                  onChange={InputEvent}
                />
                <p>
                  <button type="submit" className="signup__registerButton">
                    Register Now
                  </button>
                </p>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Comment: where have you changed the code? it seems same!

Comment: I have changes 2 things first in the registered const object and the second is changed url https to http.

Comment: I'm not getting Link in your code can you please share your code with Link

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to post errors in the question itself

your code seems quite complicated for just a simple form submission

```
 const registered = {
     name: data.name,
     phone: data.phone,
     password: data.password,
   };
```

Here data.name was string
For 400 bad request, check your node application have you defined any headers or any particular format, something like this you need to send

```
 const article = { title: 'React POST Request Example' };
const headers = { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/articles', article, { headers })
    .then(response => this.setState({ articleId: response.data.id }));
```

}

Also, for https`SSL` issue means it is expecting Secure Certificate (as you cant hit https without its certificate- which is for encrypt-decrypt ) whereas for localhost try http even if getting error try your ip address and port (usually 8080)on which app is running on backend
*shows while running the server on terminal itself*

```
for pc ip address -> go to cmd-> type ipconfig
```